# Problema com Evento KeyPressed para abrir outra janela JAVAFX

Tags: javafx, teclado

Meu problema é o seguinte, desta forma que estou abrindo a janela eu tenho um problema quanto a usar a função KeyPressed.Pois desta forma meu método precisa do parametro ActionEvent que ao usar o método getSource(), me retorna o botão e abre a janela corretamente, mas isso quando clico no botão.Aí para que a função do botão ali funcione dentro da função keyPressed, eu teria que colocar um parametro ali tambem.Tentei colocar new ActionEvent e(), o erro some porém a origem é diferente quando eu aperto enter, oq faz com que a janela n seja aberta.

Abaixo o exemplo que abre a segunda janela, ao clicar no botão.
E por ultimo o evento de KeyPressed.

Aah, a idéia é uma janela de login, dai quando eu der enter fazer as verificações e talz e abrir a outra janela.Porém só funciona clicando mesmo

private void abrirJanela(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

```
    Parent main_tela = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLTelaPrincipal.fxml"));
    Scene main = new Scene(main_tela);
    Stage st = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    st.hide();
    st.setScene(main);
    st.show();
```

}

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    btnLogar.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent event) -> {
        try {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                abrirJanela();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O JavaFX tem uma forma mais fácil de fazer um botão reagir ao evento de ENTER, basta coloca-lo [default button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html). Basicamente um botão no JavaFX pode ser de 3 tipos:

- Normal: Comportamento padrão, reagir apenas com clique;
- Default: Um botão default é um botão que também aciona com um evento de teclado do tipo VK_ENTER, desde que nenhum outro nó na cena consuma esse evento;
- Cancel: Um botão cancelar é um botão que também aciona com um evento de teclado do tipo VK_ESC, desde que nenhum outro nó na cena consuma esse evento;

Veja a maneira correta abaixo:

```
Button mybutton = new Button();
mybutton.setDefaultButton(true);

mybutton.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
    // Seu evento
});
```

Comment: Obg Irmão, resolveu meu problema.Mas poderia me explicar pq que o actionEvent dessa sua forma  funciona e quando eu crio um assim ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent()  Nao funciona? poderia me explicar??

Comment: Porque o ActionEvent é um tipo de evento, não um capturador eventos. O setOnAction recebe um EventHandler<ActionEvent>. Na forma que eu escrevi fiz uso de lambdas, na forma tradicional seria setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { ... }

Comment: Entendi, obrigado. Funcionou o jeito que vc falou, porém eu consigo acionar esse evento com o SPACE tb, e a idéia  era limitar só ao enter.Tem alguma idéia?

Comment: Outra coisa, eu queria disparar um evento ao clicar em F12,  então seria necessário eu criar um botão F12 para  poder disparar tal Evento??

Comment: Poderia colocar isso em outra pergunta? Aqui é só para comentários ... lá ficará visível para mais gente te ajudar.